# Android Studio 3.1 compilation keeps failing

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This is my application gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at ....
```

I change the ext.kotlin_version from '1.2.41' to '1.2.40' or vice versa to make it compile successfully. but I'm sick of doing this on every compilation. What exactly am I doing wrong? is there anything I'm missing.

Also I keep getting this message

```
Your version of Kotlin runtime in 'Gradle: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.40@jar' library is 1.2.40-release-66 (1.2.40), while plugin version is 1.2.41-release-Studio3.1-1.
Runtime library should be updated to avoid compatibility problems.
```

Comment: `Clean-Rebild-Restart` IDE

Comment: but why? Do I have to do it all the time?

Comment: `Do I have to do it all the time?` Nope.

Comment: Update Android Studio also.

Answer (score 0):

go to Android Studio>File>Invalidates caches/restart click invalidate and restart 
hope this helps!

Comment: didn't work. I got the same "research report of errors"